Formula for summation, is unclear.
In the book by CLRS, titled: Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition, on page #27; in the context of deriving the time-complexity of the algorithm for Insertion-sort; states:
$$\sum_{j=2}^n j = \frac{(n)(n+1)}2 -1$$
and
$$\sum_{j=2}^n (j -1) = \frac{(n)(n-1)}2$$
Am not clear, how the second formula was derived, as it should be, instead:$$\sum_{j=2}^n (j-1) = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (j) = \frac{(n-1)(n)}2-1 = \frac{(n)(n-1)}2-1$$
And, this is not in the list of errata listed here (sorted page-wise), or here.
Edit: It should be, instead:$$\sum_{j=2}^n (j-1) = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (j) = \frac{(n-1)(n)}2 = \frac{(n)(n-1)}2$$

You do not need to subtract $1$ since your sum starts with $j=1$ and not $j=2$.

Am closing it, i.e. voted for that; as found the answer while doing it.

I think you can delete it.

@Gary There is warning popping up, on attempting deletion.

Note that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
So
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k = \frac{(n-1)n}{2}
$$
Some examples if unconvinced:

